# How do include JUnit test cases as a part of Maven build?

Tags: performance, testing, maven, junit

I have existing JUnit4 test cases which I run from Eclipse and as a part of Maven. Now I am looking to perform stress tests by leveraging them. I noticed Maven is not packaging them as a part of the build. How do I go about it?

Comment: make sure, they are in the right directory (src/test/java/...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will attach the tests (and their sources) in a separate jar:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>attach-sources</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>attach-test-sources</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>test-jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>test-jar</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>test-jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Afterwards you can use them as a dependency by using the type `test-jar`.

Comment: +1. Note (to OP), the sources are not necessary if you simply wish to execute the performance tests. In which case, only the final `<plugin>` block is necessary.

Comment: I used the later plugin and it created additional abc-tests.jar of about 5kB; containing only classes for JUnit tests and abc.jar (actual code excluding JUnit classes); I have copied both jar files to ...\apache-jmeter-2.8\lib\junit folder followed by restart of JMeter to add JUnit sampler; it is not picking up these test classes. Any pointers?